# How to add sequence of JLabels right below each other?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I just ran into some issues adding a sequence of JLabels to my GUI. For example, I need to show 9 JLabels to the left of the screen right below each other.
This is what I got so far:

public MeatPanel() {

```
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Meat");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Bacon");
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Capicola");
    JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Hamburger");
    JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Pepperoni");
    JLabel label6 = new JLabel("Meatball");
    JLabel label7 = new JLabel("Sausage");
    JLabel label8 = new JLabel("Chicken");
    JLabel label9 = new JLabel("Linguica");


    add(label1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(label2, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(label3, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(label4, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(label5, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(label6, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(label7, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(label8, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(label9, BorderLayout.WEST);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(9,0));

}
```

However, they just show next to each other. How can I make it so they are right below each other, like on a list?

Comment: Have you looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712414/how-to-create-an-array-of-jlabels-in-java-to-be-printed-to-a-jframe)

Comment: So if you directly need help you can follow [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Start with [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

You're not stuck with one container/layout, you can combine them to produce complex UIs.

In your example, you're trying to add multiple components to the `WEST` position of the container, but `BorderLayout` only supports managing a single component within each of its 5 available locations.

Also, in most cases, you should set the layout manager before trying to add components to the container

The following is a common approach to using compound components/layouts to produce complex UIs

[image: Compound layout example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                // This is just a filler
                frame.add(new JPanel() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(200, 200);
                    }
                });
                frame.add(new MenuPane(), BorderLayout.WEST);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

        public MenuPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            add(new JLabel("Meat"));
            add(new JLabel("Bacon"));
            add(new JLabel("Capicola"));
            add(new JLabel("Hamburger"));
            add(new JLabel("Pepperoni"));
            add(new JLabel("Meatball"));
            add(new JLabel("Sausage"));
            add(new JLabel("Chicken"));
            add(new JLabel("Linguica"));
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use BoxLayout
more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

```
JPanel panel= new JPanel();
BoxLayout boxlayout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);// from left to rigth  
panel.setLayout(boxlayout); 

JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Meat");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Bacon");
JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Capicola");
JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Hamburger");
...
panel.add(label1);
panel.add(label2);
panel.add(label3);
panel.add(label4);
...

frame.add(panel);
```